# Desktop based Augmented Reality Application

Tags: android, desktop-application, augmented-reality

I am developing an AR based Application which contains around 30-50 models. Is it possible to develop it on Android cause there might be Memory problem in mobile devices. Is there any Desktop based AR API/SDK that can be used with 3D animation??

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can create an android application for augmented reality. There are many applications on android market especially, the one in GPS. However handling 50 models might cause a memory problem. However in high end devices like Samsung Galaxy S4 and Note 2, i dont think so you might face memory issue. Further you can also place your models in a dedicated server from where your application can fetch it. This can reduce the chances memory issues.

Some basic examples for AR on android are given here:

http://readwrite.com/2010/12/01/3-augmented-reality-tutorials#awesm=~ohLxX5jDGJLml9

AR application for desktop i haven't worked on it. I think this might help:

http://www.arlab.com/

Answer (score 1):

Does desktop application include WebGL applications in the web browser?

If so, then you might want to check out [skarf.js](http://cg.skeelogy.com/skarfjs/), a framework that I have written for handling JavaScript augmented reality libraries in [Three.js](http://threejs.org/) (JavaScript 3D library that wraps WebGL). It currently integrates two JavaScript-based augmented reality libraries: [JSARToolKit](http://fhtr.org/JSARToolKit/) and [js-aruco](https://code.google.com/p/js-aruco/).

The skarf.js framework takes care of a number of things for you, including automatic loading of models when the associated markers are detected (association is specified in a JSON file). There is also a GUI marker system which allows users to control settings using AR markers.

Integration with Three.js is just one line of code to create a Skarf instance and another line of code to update.

There are videos, live demos, source codes, examples and documentation available. Check out http://cg.skeelogy.com/skarfjs/ for more info.